# export_once like in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules

When I have something like

**File1.ts**

```js
function someFunction(){...}

export default someFunction();
```

then

**File2.ts**

```js
import File1 from "./File1";
```

**File3.ts**

```js
import File1 from "./File1";
```

The `export default someFunction();` in `File1.ts` will be executed once and the result will be cached or each import will trigger the function execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The export default someFunction(); in File1.ts will be executed once

Yes, both modules will receive the same copy of File1.ts in this case. This behavious is not TypeScript specific and can be seen in browsers or native ECMAScript modules in Node.js too.